# How to change cell background after content edited?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm importing some csv columns into a html table. I need to do some validation: if one or more than one cells for a specific column are empty then I don't allow the importing of data to my database and I highlight the empty cell with a background colour. It is a editable table; can someone explain how I can change the background colour when the empty cell has been edited and is not empty anymore?

This is what my javascript looks like so far:

```js
function NoneEmpty(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === "") return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$(document).on('click', '#import_data', function(e) {

  if (NoneEmpty(interno) == false) {

    $('.beta tr').each(function(i) {
      var column2cell = $($(this).children('td')[2]);
      if (column2cell.text() == "") {
        column2cell.css('background-color', 'red');
      }
    });

    return;

  }

});

//This is how I build the html table after uploading the csv file

$('#upload').click(function(e) {

  // Prevent form to be submitted again after page refresh
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('csv_file', $('#csv_file')[0].files[0]);
  // Append ajax action to formData so I can process the model from the controller
  formData.append('ajax_action', 'kmg_admin_fetch_csv_building_unit');

  $.ajax({

    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    // cache:false,
    processData: false,

    success: function(data) {

      if (data.notice_code == KM_ERROR_CODE) {

        alert('err');

        $('#csv_file_data').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + data.notice_message + "</div>");

      } else {

        var html = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered beta">';

        if (data.column) {
          html += '<tr>';
          for (var count = 0; count < data.column.length; count++) {
            html += '<th>' + data.column[count] + '</th>';
          }
          html += '</tr>';
        }

        if (data.row_data) {
          for (var count = 0; count < data.row_data.length; count++) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td class="scala" contenteditable>' + data.row_data[count].scala + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="piano" contenteditable>' + data.row_data[count].piano + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="interno" contenteditable="true">' + data.row_data[count].interno + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="mq" contenteditable>' + data.row_data[count].mq + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="foglio" contenteditable>' + data.row_data[count].foglio + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="particella" contenteditable>' + data.row_data[count].particella + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="sub" contenteditable>' + data.row_data[count].sub + '</td></tr>';

          }
        }

        html += '<table>';
        html += '<div align="center"><button type="button" id="import_data" class="btn btn-success">Importa unità immobilari</button></div>';

        $('#csv_file_data').html(html);
        $('#upload_csv')[0].reset();

      }

    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="upload_csv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
          <div class="input-group input-large">
            <div class="form-control uneditable-input input-fixed input-medium" data-trigger="fileinput">
              <span class="fileinput-filename"> </span>
            </div>
            <span class="input-group-addon btn default btn-file">
                                                                            <span class="fileinput-new"> Seleziona documento </span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists"> Modifica </span>
            <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" accept=".csv">
            </span>
            <a class="input-group-addon btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Rimuovi </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {#
    <div class="col-md-1"> #}
      <button type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" class="btn blue" value="Upload"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Carica file csv</button> {# </div> #}
  </div>
</form>

<div class="clearfix margin-bottom-10"> </div>
<div id="csv_file_data"></div>
```

Comment: post the HTML sample for the table please, it will help us help you and perhaps make the question solution more clear and specific here.  Also is what you reference with `#import_data` something added after the page is rendered or before/during the page render?  What is this `interno` referencing here? I suspect this entire set of code can be made much simpler but that does depend on the above.

Comment: Hi @MarkSchultheiss thanks for helping me, I've edited my answer to show you how I build and popuate the html table with values from csv file

Comment: OK, I edited it to make it a snippet - I can take a stab at this fairly quickly but it would help you if a minimal HTML from your page was in there.  (the "clicked" thing , the #csv_file_data thing etc.) Other wise I can make some assumptions... only

Comment: Hi @MarkSchultheiss I've also added the html, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an **input** event listener to your rows. So each time a row's text is an empty string make it's background red, if it's not empty make it a different color.

```js
$('.beta tr').each(function(i) {
  var column2cell = $($(this).children('td')[2]);

  if (column2cell.text() == "") {
    column2cell.css('background-color', 'red');
  }
  column2cell.on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "") {
      column2cell.css('background-color', '#dddddd');
    } else {
      column2cell.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="beta">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contentEditable="true">Company A</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Person A</td>
    <td contentEditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contentEditable="true">Company B</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Person B</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Country B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contentEditable="true">Company C</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Person C</td>
    <td contentEditable="true">Country C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @obscure thanks for your help, this is exactly what I need, one last thing how can I prevent the data to be sumbitted if there is one or more than one empty cells? In my code I did it adding return;

Comment: I guess you can leave your function as it is @pippo and just add the `column2cell.on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "") {
      column2cell.css('background-color', '#dddddd');
    } else {
      column2cell.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });` to add the listener. (unless there is something I've misinterpreted)

Comment: Note that when a table added dynamically to the page is used as in the OP's code this breaks as it is hooked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out the attribute `contenteditable="false"` is the same as if it where missing whereas `contenteditable="true"` and `contenteditable` both make it editable.

IF you wish to manipulate that dynamically `$(this).prop("contenteditable",false);` can be used.

Now we (once we get that addressed) can then key our functionality upon the actual property and then we do not have to deal with the `td[2]` and maintenance on that if you add columns etc., test that on my example where I set some of each.

Then you can use the `input` event.  Then the code is really simple here, DO use classes not `.css(` here by simply toggling those - I use bootstrap for mine here to show multiple but it could be just yours like my `empty-cell` example.  Note that if someone puts a space it gets transformed to `&nbsp;` - so I added that condition also but used the warning classes.  Test different cells with empty and space to see that in action (make it a space).

I made this code compatible with a dynamically created table by hooking it to the wrapper element `$('#csv-file-data')` and your action where you empty it - but not the document so it is specific to that if you have other tables for example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#csv-file-data')
    .on('input', 'tbody td[contenteditable]', function(event) {
      $(this)
        .toggleClass('alert alert-warning', ($(this).html() == " " || $(this).html() == "&nbsp;"))
        .toggleClass('empty-cell alert alert-danger', ($(this).html() == ""));
    });
});
```

```css
td.empty-cell {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="upload" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="table-container">
  <div id="csv-file-data">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered beta">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>scala</th>
          <th>piano</th>
          <th>interno</th>
          <th>mq</th>
          <th>foglio</th>
          <th>particella</th>
          <th>sub</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="scala" contenteditable="false">scala stuff</td>
          <td class="piano" contenteditable="false">piano stuff</td>
          <td class="interno" contenteditable="true">interno stuff</td>
          <td class="mq" contenteditable="false">mq stuff</td>
          <td class="foglio" contenteditable="false">foglio stuff</td>
          <td class="particella" contenteditable="false">particella stuff</td>
          <td class="sub" contenteditable="false">sub stuff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="scala">scala stuffcan be edited</td>
          <td class="piano">piano stuff can edit</td>
          <td class="interno" contenteditable="true">interno stuff</td>
          <td class="mq" contenteditable="false">mq stuff</td>
          <td class="foglio" contenteditable="false">foglio stuff</td>
          <td class="particella">particella stuff</td>
          <td class="sub">sub stuff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="scala" contenteditable="false">scala stuff</td>
          <td class="piano" contenteditable="false">piano stuff</td>
          <td class="interno" contenteditable="true">interno stuff</td>
          <td class="mq">mq stuff</td>
          <td class="foglio">foglio stuff</td>
          <td class="particella">particella stuff</td>
          <td class="sub">sub stuff</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Note: I left off the code that creates the table as it was not really part of the question however this code is compatible with that action event and I made some notes regarding that here.